# Рисование на JPanel'e

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

Доброго времени суток! Пишу программу похожую на MSPaint для проекта.
Вот ссылка на репозиторий с полным проектом -> https://github.com/ALazyGuy/LTP/tree/master/com/LTP/Paint.
Суть вот в чем: сейчас добавляю прорисовку прямоугольника.
Вот что есть:

```
package com.LTP.Paint;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import com.LTP.Paint.objects.Tools;

public class Paint extends JPanel {

    public static Tools tool = Tools.PEN;
    public static Color selectedColor = Color.YELLOW;
    public static Color temp = selectedColor;

    public static int size = 2;

    public Paint(){
        setSize(800, 600);

        addMouseListener(new Listener(this));
        addMouseMotionListener(new Listener(this));

        grabFocus();
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 600);
    }

}

class Listener implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener{

    private Paint paint;

    public Listener(Paint paint){
        this.paint = paint;
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        mouseClicked(e);
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if((Paint.tool == Tools.PEN)){
            Graphics g = paint.getGraphics();
            g.setColor(Paint.selectedColor);
            g.fillRect((int)(e.getX() - (Paint.size / 2)), (int)(e.getY() - (Paint.size / 2)), Paint.size, Paint.size);
        }
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}

}
```

Реализовать прорисовку хочу так:

1) Добавить переменные int x, y в класс Listener.

2) Метод mousePressed реализовать так:

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
    x = e.getX();
    y = e.getY();
    /* А тут каким-то на данный момент неизвесным мне способом,
    сохранить текущее состояние моей панели. Так, что бы 
    потом, я мог просто нарисавать это состояние. Например в переменной
    BufferedImage добавленной в классе Listener.*/
}
```

3) Метод mouseDragged реализовать как-то так:

```
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){

    if(Paint.tool == Tools.RECTANGLE){

        //На месте этого коментария рисую то сохраненное состояние на панели
        Graphics g = paint.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Paint.selectedColor);
        g.fillRect(x, y, e.getX() - x, e.getY() - y);


    }

}
```

4) Метод mouseReleased реалезую так же как и mouseDragged, но не рисую состояние панели.

Внимание вопрос! Как сохранить, а затем нарисовать это "Состояние"?

Comment: вы знаете что-нибудь про паттерн MVC?

Comment: К сожелению нет. Первый раз слышу.

Comment: рекомендую изучить. он вам пригодится в этом проекте.

Comment: Именно с решением этой задачи или вообще?

Comment: для этой задачи очень хорошо подходит. и для всех задач связанных с GUI.

Comment: А на данный момент, без знания MVC паттерна (кстати, это паттерн проектирования?), могу ли я решить эту задачу?

Comment: да - это паттерн проектирования, да - сможете решить и без него. но скорей всего вы его просто еще раз изобретете.

Comment: Ладно, спасибо большое!

Comment: @MikhailVaysman Я тут поискал, ни на docs.oracle.com, ни в wiki, не нашел инфы по этой теме, не подскажите, если знаете, где можно найти информацию?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman Я это читал, просто по другим паттернам, есть целые ГЛАВЫ из книг, а по этому, совсем мало информации.

Comment: по нему тоже очень много информации гугл выдал мне 10 миллионов ссылок. вот статья от создателя этого сайта (stackoverflow) - https://blog.codinghorror.com/understanding-model-view-controller/